Adding custom properties and metrics from an Azure Python Function App
I have the function below. Logs are successfully added to application insights however customDimensions/Properties are not. Any Pointers? Also the logger does not have logging for metrics, dont you have same options as in c#?
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 0 10 * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True, use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
     logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')

     properties = {'custom_dimensions': {'key_1': 'value_1', 'key_2': 'value_2'}}
     logging.warning('Python timer trigger function executed.', extra=properties)



Can you try to use the TelemetryClient to send custom events and properties.

Are you still looking for the solution?

The functions host default logging does not support logging with custom dimensions. To be able to see your logs with custom dimensions in appinsights, you will have to instrument with the Azure monitor OpenTelemetry distro manually in your code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=python.
An example of how you can use the distro to log custom dimensions in your Python app can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/monitor/azure-monitor-opentelemetry/samples/logging/custom_properties.py#L17
Keep in mind the logging libraries from the distro and functions host can conflict and produce duplicate telemetry. Please use this workaround: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/monitor/azure-monitor-opentelemetry#logging-issues to help resolve this.
